# Python: using sub function in order to delete all of numbers

Tags: python

I want to use sub function to delete all of numbers from text.
here's codes I tried to use but it didn't work.

```
import re
DelReg=re.compile(r'\d*  \d*\s*\w*')
DelReg.sub('', '44- car, 195- internet, 222- display, 187-airline, 217-oil, 177- ad')
```

Can you tell me the right code to sub all of numbers to ' ' ?

Thank you.

Comment: please provide sample output.

Answer (score 0):

No need to write big regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> a="44- car, 195- internet, 222- display, 187-airline, 217-oil, 177- ad"
>>> re.sub('\d+','',a)
'- car, - internet, - display, -airline, -oil, - ad'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the code was exactly I was looking for.